# Number of arguments to a method in java

Tags: java, performance, methods, arguments, pass-by-reference

I am looking for an example that demonstrate performance improvement (speed) when running a method with several arguments (let's say 5 arguments) vs. running a method with only one argument (holding the 5 arguments).

Thanks

Comment: I don't see a question anywhere...

Comment: How do you demonstrate it is faster?

Comment: Why would 1 argument be slower? because it has to allocate the object that contains the arguments? Memory allocation and GC is expensive, compared to just pushing the arguments on the stack. Make your own example.

Answer (score -1):

According to my understanding, you may want to see the performance improvement when you use 5 methods with only 1 argument, comparing to 1 method with 5 argument.

I think you can use Date to calculate eclipsed time before and after running the method.

The pseudocode would be:

1. long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
2. Call the method1, with 5 parameters.
3. long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
4. long time1 = end - start;
5. Do it 5 times, to get an average time eclipsed.
6. Do the same to the other method, now get time2 as the second average time eclipsed.
7. Compare them.

To clearly see the performance improvement, **(time1-time2)** is the time saved, if time1-time2 is above 0.